Why Does Warming Up Improve my Audiation?
If I warm up my audiation skills through scale singing and arpeggio singing for example, this will in turn improve my audiation noticeably.  By audiation in this case I mean purely audiation, not the partly related skill of vocalization. Singing scales and intervals does certainly also improve my vocalization, but it also improves my audiation, and it is the audiation aspect I am inquiring about. This question might appear to be a no-brainer, of course warming up should improve one's audiation, but on closer inspection it is a good question. for example, other types of skills such as visualization do not (I would testify) require or benefit much from "warming up." Visualization seems to be a skill ready to go at any moment, whereas audiation I find really needs some warm-up exercises in order to get it going. If audiation has any parallels to visualization then it follows that audiation should not need much warm-up time.

Does your audiation improve for the next hour when you do your singing exercises? Does your audiation regress when you don't do your singing exercises the next day?

Audiation of a written score is a very specific task.   I'm struggling to define a 'visualization' task of the same sort.
